# Is it OK to have an empty while block when using WaitOne with named mutexes for IPC?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, ipc

Basically, multiple instances of the same process will do this:

```
using (var mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, MUTEX_NAME))
{
    while (!mutex.WaitOne(100)) { /* wait to acquire mutex from other process */ }
    try 
    { 
        doSynchronizedWork();
    }
    finally 
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Will there be any pitfalls? Can a *process* exit without releasing the mutex? Will an `AbandonedMutexException` actually be thrown if that happens? Or will another process just acquire the mutex? Something else?

### Edit:

Looks like the correct way should be (at least my scenario) would be to do this:

```
using (var mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, MUTEX_NAME))
{
    bool lockObtained = false;
    while (!lockObtained)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!mutex.WaitOne()) { /* wait to acquire mutex */ }
            lockObtained = true;
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException ignored) 
        { 
            // mutex abandoned by another 
            // process before that process completed.
            // We can now try to obtain it again.
        }
    }
    try
    {
        doSynchronizedWork();
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your thread can wait a sufficient amount of time, you can call the [`Thread.Yield`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield.aspx) to give a system resources to another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the point of this? Simply wait without a timeout.

When a process exits all resources are cleaned up. An `AbandonedMutexException` must be assumed to be able to happen in IPC scenarios because the other process might fail at any time (due to a bug or out of memory and such).

In case you are doing this so that `Thread.Abort` works: `Thread.Abort` is super dangerous. Leave a comment and I'll be able to help you migrate to something better.